British movie about a teenager pretending to be a business owner to win a bet
I remember seeing this British movie on TV in the early 90's. It originates probably from the same period. These are the details that I seem to remember:
The plot revolves around a teenager placing a bet with his friend that he will be the owner of a company worth 1 million pounds within a certain period of time, starting with absolutely no money.
The boy would then buy a suit on credit, has free trial business cards printed and has car salesmen acting as his chauffeur during test drives. I think he also hired a young woman as an assistant.
In the end, he wins the bet by placing a bid of one million pounds at a real estate auction.

Sounds like the British TV-movie Money for Nothing from 1993, which was technically an episode of the anthology series Screen One. From IMDb:

[A] teenager who has a bet with a friend that he can't be worth £1 million in a week. The lad, played by Christien Anholt, manages to bluff everyone by getting a suit on loan, a car on loan, a phone on loan, sets up a bogus company, changes his name to sound more impressive, bids on property in auctions which he can't pay for, and tries to set up deals with various corporations in the hope that they will invest with him. Along the way there's romance and a threat of danger when he makes a deal with a ruthless American corporation.

Here are the first few minutes:




Indeed. That's the one. Thank you very much.
